# Compare date part in where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, exception, linq-to-entities, datetime-comparison

When tried to condition the where statement to only compare the date part of the datetime field using this code,

```
var list =  products.Where(x => ((DateTime)x.PurchaseDate).Date >= dt_SelectDate.Value.Date);
```

I used the `(DateTime)` conversion because EF don't recognize the `.GetValueOrDefault()`, and the `PurchaseDate` field is nullable.

the error I got is

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: so PurchaseDate's type is nullable DateTime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to the the EntityFunctions.TruncateTime method to compare (just) dates.

Here's the MSDN description: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx